# how to change parameter variable value in a recursive macro?

Tags: freemarker

I want to show a number sequence in black color, and show nested sequence number in red. Here is my marco code:

```
<#macro test datas isNested>
    <#list datas as d>
    <#if d?is_enumerable>
        <#local isNested = true>
        <#if isNested>
            <#-- become red if it is nested -->
            Hi, I am going to be red!
                            <#-- some business code -->
        </#if>
        <@test d isNested/>
    <#else>
        <#if isNested>
            <span style="color:red;">${d}</span>
        <#else>
            ${d}
        </#if>
    </#if>
</#list>
</#macro>
```

call it like this:

```
<@test [1,2,3,[4,5],6,7] false/>
```

I want it to be:

```
1 2 3 Hi, I am going to be red! 4 5 6 7
```

only 4 and 5 show in red.
But now I get this:

```
1 2 3 Hi, I am going to be red! 4 5 6 7
```

all of 4 5 6 7 are show in red.

I think this line of code `<#local isNested = true>` play the trick. I also try to use `assign`, `global`, all of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 are black.

so how should I do?
Thx in advance.

**PS**:
    I don't know how to make code show in red in stackoverflow, if any one knows plz helps me to edit my code.

Comment: You never set `isNested` to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not FreeMarker-specific. You flip the `isNested` local variable (which also holds the parameter value) to `true` before the recursive `@test` call, and you leave if so after the recursive macro call has returned. So when the iteration of `6` and `7` comes, `isNested` is already `true`. You should not set the `isNested` at all, just pass `true` to the recursive call. Here:

```
<#macro test datas isNested=false>
    <#list datas as d>
        <#if d?is_enumerable>
            Hi, I am going to be red!
            <@test d true />
        <#else>
            <#if isNested>
                <span style="color:red;">${d}</span>
            <#else>
                ${d}
            </#if>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#macro>

<@test [1,2,3,[4,5],6,7] />
```